# AngularJS routing "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once" loop

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to make an app to learn to work with AngularJS and rails. Only when I try to rout with angular I get this printed in te console "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once" in an infinite loop.

If followed this [tutorial](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/) until the problem occurred from there I've searched a lot here on Stackoverflow, but could not find a solution to my problem.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Deadlines', ['ngRoute', 'templates'], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  }).otherwise( { redirectTo: '/'} );

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning shows that you have added more than one angular js library. Better to remove any one angular library.

Comment: I could not find any second copies of angular that could have caused the problem, I have found an other solution to my problem that also suggests that this was not the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue through using [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for angular. I found out that this problem was not occurring when I was trying to recreate the issue with just HTML and Angular. So it has something to do with the combination of rails and Angular. I can't explain why [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is the solution for my problem cause I'm still a noob, but it works and I can continue learning to build apps.

app.js

```
angular.module('Deadlines', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
    .config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            })
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        }])
    .config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

Here is my current app.js for people facing the same problems